# Could I mask my IP to be like my mobile data IP?

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, ip

I don't have static IP, people at home don't have static IPs, in my country.The ISP at work gave my company static IPs for the office, and in order to protect itself against DDOS, he went to mobile data providers, got all their IP range, whitelisted that and blocked any other IP.

You can get to the website, but you can't ssh, unless you're tethering or in the office. I'm not sure this is the smart thing to do, but this is what the ISP has done, that's what I was told.

So now if I want to ssh, I either have to be at the office or tethering. Is it possible to mask my wifi IP for it to appear like my IP when I'm tethering? Or something like that?

The ISP can't whitelist my home IP simply because I don't have a static IP, otherwise, he would have done it.

Comment: To seith and smock, I deleted my previous question, after asking the IT department for details and this what they said

Comment: Your IT department should simply remove these ridiculous firewall rules. They don’t protect against anything if mobile IP ranges are still allowed.

Comment: @DanielB I believe the ISP should remove them, I'd like to talk to them, but i'm not in a position to do that, I'm just a programmer. CTO hates that as well, maybe he has a better chance to argue with them

Comment: If you would mask your IP, the other end would simply try to connect to that ip and your connection would fail. If you want to have a static IP, Ask your work to setup VPN.